# Strange line in C# camera code

Tags: c#

My team is working on documentation for a robot project. We're currently documenting some camera code but we don't understand some lines.

```
public Mat Image { get; set; }
public double GyroAngle { get; set; }
```

Could anyone explain what these lines are doing? If the `GyroAngle` is simply a `double` why does it have `{ get; set; }`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `GyroAngle` is a *property* (*auto-implemented property* to be exact) not a *field*; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) has some useful info.

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Jane";
```

> The class that is shown in the previous example is mutable. Client code can change the values in objects after they are created. In complex classes that contain significant behavior (methods) as well as data, it is often necessary to have public properties. However, for small classes or structs that just encapsulate a set of values (data) and have little or no behaviors, you should either make the objects immutable by declaring the set accessor as private (immutable to consumers) or by declaring only a get accessor (immutable everywhere except the constructor). For more information, see [How to: Implement a Lightweight Class with Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383979.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is not strange at all.

1. A field cannot be used in interfaces but properties can.
2. Most .NET binding can be done against a property. Not fields
3. You can change the implementation of a property and keep the contract so no dependent code breaks. For example, in the setter you may add validation. You may not have validation today, but if you do in the future, you can add that. If it was a field, and you change it to property, many bad things will happen such as binary serialization may break.

Some tools will also yell at you if you expose a field as public.